# Does dynamically-linked binaries use crt in linux?

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking, crt

I know that statically-linked binaries use crt (C Runtime) when linking, as it passes cmd arguments to `main`, deals with TLS storage, etc. However, inside a dynamically-linked binary, there is no such codes, so crt is not linked to it when linking.

But after searching keyword "crt" in source codes of `ld`, `glibc` and even linux kernel, I can't find any clue that dynamically-linked binaries use crt.

So how does those dynamically-linked binaries handle cmd arguments passing, TLS initialization, etc. without crt?

Comment: Dynamically linked binaries also "use crt".

Comment: The linux kernel isn't reponsible, the C standard library implementation is. Glibc has the startup code in the `csu` source folder (and the `sysdeps` folder for system-dependent details), see https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=csu. There are also the `crtbegin*` and `crtend*` files which are supplied by the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter if the binary links with no other libraries or does link. The crt is always "statically" included inside the executable.

Let's do real life, consider the following setup:

```
==> main.c <==
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        puts(argv[0]);
}


==> compile.sh <==
#!/bin/bash
set -x
gcc -static main.c -o static.out
gcc main.c -o dynamic.out
ldd static.out
ldd dynamic.out
./static.out
./dynamic.out
objdump -D static.out | grep -C10 '<_start>:'
objdump -D dynamic.out | grep -C10 '<_start>:'
```

The `./compile.sh` script execution outputs:

```
+ gcc -static main.c -o static.out
+ gcc main.c -o dynamic.out
+ ldd static.out
        not a dynamic executable
+ ldd dynamic.out
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc226e7000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f079878e000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f07989cf000)
+ ./static.out
./static.out
+ ./dynamic.out
./dynamic.out
+ objdump -D static.out
+ grep -C10 '<_start>:'
0000000000401508 <read_encoded_value_with_base.cold>:
  401508:       50                      push   %rax
  401509:       67 e8 cb fb ff ff       addr32 call 4010da <abort>

000000000040150f <__gcc_personality_v0.cold>:
  40150f:       67 e8 c5 fb ff ff       addr32 call 4010da <abort>
  401515:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    cs nopw 0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  40151c:       00 00 00 
  40151f:       90                      nop

0000000000401520 <_start>:
  401520:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
  401524:       31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
  401526:       49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
  401529:       5e                      pop    %rsi
  40152a:       48 89 e2                mov    %rsp,%rdx
  40152d:       48 83 e4 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
  401531:       50                      push   %rax
  401532:       54                      push   %rsp
  401533:       45 31 c0                xor    %r8d,%r8d
  401536:       31 c9                   xor    %ecx,%ecx
+ objdump -D dynamic.out
+ grep -C10 '<_start>:'
    1026:       ff 25 e4 2f 00 00       jmp    *0x2fe4(%rip)        # 4010 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
    102c:       0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000001030 <puts@plt>:
    1030:       ff 25 e2 2f 00 00       jmp    *0x2fe2(%rip)        # 4018 <puts@GLIBC_2.2.5>
    1036:       68 00 00 00 00          push   $0x0
    103b:       e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmp    1020 <_init+0x20>

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000001040 <_start>:
    1040:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1044:       31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
    1046:       49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
    1049:       5e                      pop    %rsi
    104a:       48 89 e2                mov    %rsp,%rdx
    104d:       48 83 e4 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
    1051:       50                      push   %rax
    1052:       54                      push   %rsp
    1053:       45 31 c0                xor    %r8d,%r8d
    1056:       31 c9                   xor    %ecx,%ecx
```

We can learn that:

- static.out is static executable
- dynamic.out is dynamic executable
- both executables include code for `_start` symbol
- `_start` symbol comes from crt

Ergo, both executables include crt inside them.